# show function's uniqueness

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$$\ f:A \to C $$
$$\ g:A \to B $$
prove that necessary and sufficient condition to exist $\ h:B \to C $ such that $\ f = h \circ g $ is $\ \forall x,y \in A $ and $\ g(x)=g(y) \Rightarrow f(x)=f(y) $. and prove to guarantee the uniqueness of h, g ought to be surjective.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Do you have any thoughts on the problem and can share what you have to done as this helps responders? Regards

Comment: You want $f=h\circ g$ for this to make sense. But $h$ will not be unique without further assumptions. Under the condition, it is uniquely defined on the range of $g$. And it is unique iff $g$ is surjective.

Comment: i am sorry. my mistake. i exchanged to $\ f = h \circ g $

Comment: Two conditions to be added: I. [probe](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/probe?q=probe) $\to$ [prove](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prove?q=prove). II. To guarantee the uniqueness of $h$, $g$ ought to be surjective.

Comment: thank you for your answer. i reflect on myself. but original problem exist without surjective condition of g. i wonder the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us show that the uniqueness statement is not true, without the assumption that $g$ is surjective:
Let $A=B=C=\mathbb R$. And let $f(x)=x, g(x)=x^2$. Then $h(x)=\sqrt{(x)}$ certainly is one function satisfying the requirements, and so is $h(x)=\begin{cases}\sqrt{x}&x\ge0\\1&x<0\end{cases}$. In fact, the behaviour of $h$ at negative $x\in \mathbb R$ is totally irrelevant, so that it goes without saying that $h$ is not unique.
Now let us show the conditions.

> Suppose that $(g(x)=g(y))\implies (f(x)=f(y))$. Then we define $h(x)$ as $f(y)$ if $x=g(y)$; our hypothesis just says that $h$ is well-defined, so the existence is established.
>   Now suppose that there is such $h$ that $f=h\circ g$. If $g(x)=g(y)$ then undoubtedly $f(x)=h(g(x))=h(g(y))=f(y)$. Hence $(g(x)=g(y))\implies(f(x)=f(y))$.

In fact, our construction of the functin $h$ shows that, if $g:A\to B$ is surjective, then $h$ is unique, as it must be the function as constructed above.